# 'react-admin' does not contain an export named 'Query'

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am trying to integrate `<Query>` component in my code but I am getting following error.

```
 ./src/component/promos/PromosCreate.js

54:6-11 'react-admin' does not contain an export named 'Query'.
```

All my import statements in `PromosCreate.js`

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import {
  Create,
  DateInput,
  TextInput,
  LongTextInput,
  ImageInput,
  TabbedForm,
  FormTab,
  SelectInput,
  FileInput,
  CheckboxGroupInput,
  required,
  ImageField,
  FileField,
  Query,
} from 'react-admin';
```

Comment: What version of react-admin are you using ?

Comment: Query was released in version 2.8 of react-admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Query>` component was introduced in react-admin `2.8`, see the [release note](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/releases/tag/v2.8.0).

If a component appears in the documentation but is not available on your environment, the generic answer is to **upgrade your version of react-admin**.